# Any tools for import and export between SQL Azure and Sql Server 2008 R2 DB

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, azure-sql-database

All, I am looking for some 3rd tools or ways to import data from SQL Azure data source to the Sql Server 2008R2 DB in local network. help. thanks.

Comment: I already found the `DTSWizard.exe` of MS Sql Server 2008 R2 is enough for me.  can select source and destination , and mapping fields etc, It works fine. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm fond of [Red Gate's SQL toolbelt](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-toolbelt/)... They have lots of cool tools and as a last ditch effort they will script the entire db for you (data and all) as pure sql statements, which should get around most sql server/sql azure issues as you could just debug the script for any incompatibilities (though going TO MS Sql Server should have much fewer issues than going to Sql Azure)...

Also, I didn't know if [this technique](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff951624.aspx#CopyingDb) would work for you

Comment: No, unfortunately... It's quite expensive (about 2 grand), but there is a free trial and it may get you past the hump...

Comment: Thanks, I already found a solution , please check the comments below my post .